What are the main pros and cons of the most commonly used weighting methods?
There are many methods to generate balancing weights in observational studies (see, for example, the many methods implemented in the amazing WeighIt package).
I have seen some great discussions about why one would prefer to use matching/weighting over regressing on confounders, but I have never found a paper or discussion about the pros and cons of the most widely used weighting methods.

Can someone explain the pros and cons of the most frequently used methods for weighting? (such as (generalized) linear models, boosted modeling, entropy balancing, energy balancing, etc.?)
Are these pros and cons comparable when estimating a treatment effect or accounting for non-respondents in a survey?

Thanks a lot.

This is a good question, and I think papers could be (and some have been) written about this topic. I'll do my best to answer in a somewhat succinct way. My answer assumes ones knows about the variety of weighting methods available.
The ideal weights are those that optimize three qualities:

Balance, the degree to which the treatment groups are similar to each other on the distribution of covariates
Representativeness, the degree to which the treatment groups are similar to the target population on the distribution of covariates
Precision, the degree of uncertainty in the effect estimate (i.e., the reciprocal of the standard error)

The goal of weighting is to find a method that optimizes all three, as doing so yields an effect estimate that is unbiased for the target parameter and precise.
The different weighting methods vary on how well they achieve and balance these three qualities. Some try hard to balance and be representative but decrease precision, whereas others balance well and maintain precision but omit representativeness. How to decide how to trade off these three qualities requires substantive knowledge about which can be sacrificed in a given problem. For example:

Maybe you don't think the true potential outcome model is very complicated, so you don't require balance on higher order terms and can instead focus on representativeness and precision
Maybe you don't think the treatment effect is heterogeneous and so maintaining representativeness is not as important as achieving balance and precision
Maybe your sample is large or your effect size is large enough to be detected with a small sample, and so maintaining precision is less important than is reducing bias by achieving balance and representativeness

In these cases, the best weighting method is the one that optimizes the criteria most important for your analysis.
In practice, there are features that are fundamentally unknown to the analyst but that determine how effective a weighting method is. Error in an effect estimate is a function of imbalance between treatment groups on specific features of the covariate distribution that are determined by the true potential outcome-generating model, which is unknown to analysts. That means we don't know how well a given level of measured balance corresponds to actual error reduction in the effect estimate. This error is also due to imbalance (i.e., lack of representativeness) between each treatment group and the target population on specific features of the covariate distribution related to effect heterogeneity that are also determined by the true potential outcome-generating model. The precision of an effect estimate is a function of the variability of the weights, which is usually measured using the effective sample size (ESS), but precision is also related to imbalance in opaque ways such that two sets of weights with the same ESS could have drastically different actual precisions. Because of these fundamental unknowns, we have to either make strong assumptions (i.e., about the potential outcome-generating model) that are liable to be false or rely on theoretical qualities that concern unseen features of the data or model (e.g., convergence rates for certain modeling methods).
Although these features are the main ones that one should care about in an ideal world, in practice the world is messy, and constraints related to computation, reproducibility, and comprehensibility also come into play. That is, some weighting methods are computationally infeasible with some datasets (e.g., with many units or many covariates). Some weighting methods involve a random component and so are not generally reproducible without setting a seed and will yield different results on each run. Some weighting methods may perform well but are hard to explain, making one's audience lose faith in the analysis. How uncertainty is quantified also matters for the method; some methods have asymptotic approximations to the standard error of the weighted treatment effect, and others might require conservative approximations or the use of the bootstrap to estimate uncertainty.
Below is a quick table that summarizes some of the methods available in WeightIt along with their pros and cons. When I mention "theoretical guarantees", I mean guarantees that the method could estimate the true effect in a large enough sample without strong knowledge of the potential outcome-generating model.



Method
Pros
Cons




GLM propensity score (method = "glm")
Easy to use; comprehensible to audiences; works on large datasets; fast; asymptotic approximations to variance available
No theoretical guarantees; doesn't optimize any criteria (though ATO weights optimize balance and precision); often performs poorly; balance is only approximate


GBM propensity score (method = "gbm")
Comprehensible; flexible model; works on large datasets; explicitly targets balance
Slow; often performs poorly; balance is only approximate; no good variance approximation


Entropy balancing (method = "ebal")
Fast; optimizes balance, precision, and representativeness; obtain exact balance; asymptotic approximations to variance available
Limited theoretical guarantees (requires strong assumptions on outcome model); works poorly with poor overlap


Covariate balancing propensity score (method = "cbps")
Obtains exact balance; comprehensible; asymptotic approximations to variance available
Limited theoretical guarantees; slow for large data


Superlearner propensity score (method = "super")
Theoretical guarantees; flexible model; comprehensible
Slow; stochastic element; doesn't optimize balance, representativeness, or precision; no good variance approximation


Energy balancing (method = "energy")
Theoretical guarantees; optimizes balance and representativeness; flexible; can be used with many covariates
Slow or impossible for large datasets; no good variance approximation; hard to explain



There are a few methods I didn't mention because they have similar qualities to these methods but differ only in subtle ways. NPCBPS (method = "npcbps") is similar to entropy balancing but worse; stable balancing weights (method = "optweight") is similar to entropy balancing but allows finer control, can be tuned to perform will with poor overlap, but lacks some theoretical properties and doesn't have a variance estimator; BART propensity scores (method = "bart") are similar to Superlearner propensity scores but require fewer decisions; inverse probability tilting (method = "ipt") is similar to entropy balancing and CBPS.
This is an incomplete list and some may disagree with how I've described them. I've also tried to keep this somewhat short, so I didn't provide citations or clarifications about theoretical properties or variance estimators. Let me know if there are specific methods you have questions about and I'll try to expound.
My recommendation is to try several methods and see which optimizes the three key criteria in your dataset. In many cases, energy balancing will do well when it is feasible, but for large datasets, GBM and BART tend to do well, too. Entropy balancing is good when trying to retain precision and you don't want to bootstrap to compute the variance.
